# Get the actual calls that failed in the assertion of a mock using the assert_has_calls method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm mocking a method, and then testing if it gets the calls I expect.

```
@mock.patch('connecter.Connector')
def test_queries(mock_connect):
    mock_connect().execute.return_value = [(55223,)]
    connector = connecter.Connector()
    expected_calls = [call(), call(), call().execute('SELECT * FROM table1;'), call().execute('SELECT * FROM table2;')]
    mock_connect.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)
```

So, this works. But if it fails, it simply tells me the assertion fails and I get no details whatsoever what element (what call) actually failed. Is there a way to get that information so that the tests are more informative?

I couldn't find anything obvious in the documentation.

Comment: You could check the calls separately using `assert_any_call`, at least if you are not interested in the call sequence (`assert_has_calls` does not check the call sequence by default either, though you can change that using `any_order=False`).

Comment: Isn't any_order False by default? Their documentation seems to point toward this. Order does matter for me. I guess I'll have to go with assert_any_call first for each call, and then the assert_has_call to test the order

Comment: You are right about the default - I misread this obviously. Good plan - I would probably write a helper that does both checks.